# Do multiple Azure VMs migrating at the same time slow down synchronization?

Tags: azure, data-migration

I noticed that the slowest part of migrating an Azure VM to a different region using Disaster Recovery is waiting for the initial sync to complete.

If I try to migrate multiple VMs at the same time, will that cause this initial sync to slow down for each machine that's being transferred?

Comment: probably a good question to the product team, not to stack overflow